# Is it possible for the synchronization control bit not to be set even though TCP segments are sent and received? Why? Please give examples

Tags: tcp, connection, ip, network-protocols, rfc

I am currently reading the request for comments 793 about the transmission control protocol. Here is a link to the document: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.

**First of all, is it possible for the SYN control bit not to be set even though TCP segments are sent and received?**

According to the following excerpt, when the synchronization control bit is present, the sequence number is the sequence number of the first data octet in this segment.

**Does this mean that even when the synchronization control bit is not
present, the segment can be sent and received?**
**I thought that if the synchronization control bit is not present, it is 0. If it is 0, then the sockets (transmission control protocol devices) are not connected. If they are not connected, then segments cannot be received or sent. Is this logic flawed and if so why?**
**Honestly, I would like to ask what is the difference between the following:

- the sequence number of the first data octet in this segment
- the initial sequence number
- the first data octet** (I do not why, but in this context, it is treated like a number because it is equal to ISN+1. I guess that it is short for "the sequence number of the first data octet", but it is first by definition, so it should be one and equal to the initial sequence number. I can only say that my logic is flawed, but cannot say why.)

***Does SYN become 0 after the first data octet in the segment has been received?***

Please note that I am have just begun studying protocols, TCP, IP, headers, sockets, and nearly all of the rest of this stuff. If you notice any illogical statements in my reasoning please let me know!
I will be very thankful for any explanation that even elementary students would understand. Thank you!

***"Sequence Number:  32 bits
The sequence number of the first data octet in this segment (except when SYN is present). If SYN is present the sequence number is the initial sequence number (ISN) and the first data octet is ISN+1."***

Answer (score 0):

A TCP connections starts with an initial TCP handshake. The handshake **requires** that the SYN bit is set - otherwise it would not be the initial TCP handshake.

While it is possible (using raw sockets) to send IP packets with protocol TCP and a TCP header and never use the SYN bit this would not be actual TCP but only some protocol which resembles in part TCP. It would not be possible to use this for exchanging data with real TCP peers and stateful firewalls would also block these packets since they don't belong to any known TCP connection.